# Why is my textbox binding to an old object that has been added to a collection? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

**View:**

```
<StackPanel ....>
.....
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Customer.FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="100">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyUp">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CreateFullNameCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>

    <TextBox Text="{Binding Customer.LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="100">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyUp">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CreateFullNameCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>

    <TextBox Text="{Binding Customer.FullName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="100"/>
    <Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddCustomerCommand}" Width="90"/>
</StackPanel>
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerList}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Margin="0,27,0,0"/>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
internal class CustomerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Customer customer;
    private ObservableCollection<Customer> customerList;

    public CustomerViewModel()
    {
        customer = new Customer();
        customerList = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();

        CreateFullNameCommand = new CustomerCreateFullNameCommand(this);
        AddCustomerCommand = new CustomerAddCustomerCommand(this);
    }

    public Customer Customer //read only
    {
        get { return customer; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Customer> CustomerList //read only
    {
        get { return customerList; }
    }

    public void JoinName()
    {
        Customer.FullName = String.Format("{0}, {1}", Customer.LastName, customer.FirstName);
    }

    public void AddCustomer()
    {
        customerList.Insert(0, customer);
        customer = new Customer();
    }

    #region Commands

    public ICommand CreateFullNameCommand
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public ICommand AddCustomerCommand
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    #endregion


    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I also have set `DataContext = new CustomerViewModel()`

So when I'm typing a name into the textboxes they bind exactly the way I want them to, they dynamically update the FullName textbox.  My problem is that when I click add, it adds the customer to the customerList in the ViewModel and it updates the xaml and shows the customer inside the datagrid.  My problem is that when the customer object news after the add the textboxes do not display blank again.  I have also tried in the customer constructor to set the values to empty strings, this solves the problem with resetting the name but when I start to enter a new customer in the textboxes, it will start to update the item that I just added in the datagrid.  What is weird is it will only change the first letter then it seems like it is working.

I want to know the best way to instantiate a new customer object that will reflect a new one in the textboxes as well as not edit the one that I just added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
public Customer Customer //read only
{
    get { return customer; }
}
```

you should write

```
public Customer Customer //read only
{
    get { return customer; }
    private set {
        if (value != customer)
        {
            customer = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Customer");
        }
    }
}
```

and use

```
Customer = new Customer();
```

instead of

```
customer = new Customer();
```

This is necessary to inform the view that the `Customer` property now has a new value.

Comment: Sweet that did it! Thank! So another question, even when I was newing the private customer object why would it change my object that was inserted into the collection?

Comment: I am not sure, but I guess that WPF reads the `Customer`  property again when the view tries to store a value via the `Customer.LastName` path.